# Cannot execute binary file - Zabbix external scripts on CentOS

Tags: linux, bash, expect, zabbix

Problem: We use Zabbix as monitoring system. In addition to using its built in items, we also use something called external scripts feature ([this](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/external)), where custom scripts can be written and called via Zabbix. The problem facing here is its getting timed out. Script is simple expect file which goes inside a device and pulls some data. This works when called via root. But when called via Zabbix user, its complaining

```
/usr/bin/expect: /usr/bin/expect: cannot execute binary file
```

Script looks like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set host "IP_ADDRESS"
set uname "username"
set pwd "password"
set prompt "#|>|:|\\\$";
set val ""
set domain [lindex $argv 0]
log_user 0
set timeout -1
spawn /usr/bin/ssh "$uname@$host"
expect "$uname@$host's password:"
send "$pwd\n"
sleep 1
#expect -re "$prompt"
expect ">"
sleep 1
send "show wireless rf-domain statistics detail on $domain | grep Signals\r"
sleep 1
expect  ">"
set val $expect_out(buffer)
send "exit\n"
puts $val
```

This is named as rf_signal.exp. Its called via a wrapper shell script named rf_signal.

```
#!/bin/bash
val=$(/usr/bin/expect '/usr/local/etc/scripts/rf_signal.exp' $1 | grep 'RF Signals' | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d',' -f1 | cut -d' ' -f3 | sed -e 's/\s//g') 
echo "$val"
```

And if  called as root, this works fine for example

```
[root@zbx-proxy2 externalscripts]# pwd
/usr/local/share/zabbix/externalscripts
[root@zbx-proxy2 externalscripts]# whoami
root
[root@zbx-proxy2 externalscripts]# /usr/local/share/zabbix/externalscripts/rf_signal DOMAIN_NAME
241
[root@zbx-proxy2 externalscripts]#
```

Where as if I call as zabbix user I am getting, cannot execute binary file error. With expect as a path

```
[root@zbx-proxy2 externalscripts]# runuser -l zabbix /usr/bin/expect /usr/local/share/zabbix/externalscripts/rf_signal 
/usr/bin/expect: /usr/bin/expect: cannot execute binary file
[root@zbx-proxy2 externalscripts]#
```

Without expect as a path, it waits -

```
[root@zbx-proxy2 externalscripts]# runuser -l zabbix  /usr/local/share/zabbix/externalscripts/rf_signal
```

PSTree command output shows it calls expect and contents inside the file

```
[root@zbx-proxy2 ~]# pstree -p 26295
runuser(26295)---bash(26296)---bash(26309)-+-cut(26312)
                                           |-cut(26313)
                                           |-cut(26314)
                                           |-expect(26310)---ssh(26316)
                                           |-grep(26311)
                                           `-sed(26315)
```

PS details.

```
[root@zbx-proxy2 ~]# ps aux | grep zabbix  | grep -v "proxy\|agent\|fping"
root     26295  0.0  0.0 130700  1388 pts/3    S+   15:46   0:00 runuser -l zabbix /usr/local/share/zabbix/externalscripts/rf_signal
zabbix   26296  0.0  0.0 108184  1628 pts/3    S+   15:46   0:00 -bash /usr/local/share/zabbix/externalscripts/rf_signal
zabbix   26309  0.0  0.0 108184   576 pts/3    S+   15:46   0:00 -bash /usr/local/share/zabbix/externalscripts/rf_signal
zabbix   26310  0.0  0.0 115336  2260 pts/3    S+   15:46   0:00 /usr/bin/expect /usr/local/etc/scripts/rf_signal.exp
zabbix   26311  0.0  0.0 103260   868 pts/3    S+   15:46   0:00 grep RF Signals
zabbix   26312  0.0  0.0 100972   676 pts/3    S+   15:46   0:00 cut -d: -f2
zabbix   26313  0.0  0.0 100972   672 pts/3    S+   15:46   0:00 cut -d, -f1
zabbix   26314  0.0  0.0 100972   676 pts/3    S+   15:46   0:00 cut -d  -f3
zabbix   26315  0.0  0.0 105268   872 pts/3    S+   15:46   0:00 sed -e s/\s//g
zabbix   26316  0.0  0.0  59856  3220 pts/14   Ss+  15:46   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh username@IP_ADDRESS
root     26688  0.0  0.0 105324   912 pts/7    S+   15:47   0:00 grep zabbix
[root@zbx-proxy2 ~]#
```

All the scripts have read and execute permissions to all the users. And expect/grep/cut - whatever used inside the scripts are having read/execute permissions. What could be the issue?

Comment: Why not use the built-in Zabbix SSH items - https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/ssh_checks ?

Comment: downvoted because of the "don't downvote" plea

Comment: I can't use ssh items as i need to parse and generate pretty output hence the shell script wrapper.

Comment: Really bad, despite requesting not to downvote, someone wants deliberately downvote and discourage posting in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use:

```
su - zabbix -c "/usr/local/share/zabbix/externalscripts/rf_signal"
```

to run the script instead of `runuser`.

Usually, the `zabbix` user has `/sbin/nologin` set up as a login shell, which means you won't be able to login via `ssh` onto the respective server. You may check `/etc/passwd` on the remote server to verify this.

As an additional note, you may use `expect -d` to enable debug in your expect script and see where it fails. Set expect's `timeout` to a different value like `180` (3 minutes) as opposed to `-1` otherwise it will never exit.

Comment: I got the same result of can't run binary file to su -, hence used runuser. Inside the script its not using zabbix as a user to do ssh, but a different username which is hardcoded inside the script. Let me try with expect -d and setting 180s timeout.